# elasticsearch script fields, can't get value of nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

as title said, I can't get value of nested fields.

`doc['field.iner_field'].value` returns `null`.

`doc['field.iner_field1'].values` returns an empty array.

but I can get value of normal fields.

`doc['normal'].field` worked.

I use groovy as script language

why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 `doc.field.iner_field.value`